# Multiple Selectors with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Can I select two elements with Jquery at the one time?

For example I tried this but it only selected the first element:

```
$('.loginStaff' || '.loginClient').click(function(){
    $('.login_form').toggle();
});
```

I also tried but this only selected the last element:

```
$('.loginStaff' && '.loginClient').click(function(){
    $('.login_form').toggle();
});
```

Thanks!!!
Global

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a comma to separate your selectors and it will match the combined results of all:

```
$('.loginStaff,.loginClient').click(function(){
  //..
});
```

More info:

- [Selectors/multiple](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple)

Comment: how many could we say we can use? (i mean, what it's recomended?)